# Composer not updating required library

Tags: php, git, laravel-4, composer-php

I'm using the Laravel framework and wanted to include a library from GitHub. This is my full `composer.json` file:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "laravel/framework": "4.0.*",
        "intervention/helper": "dev-master" <- this is what I've added
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "app/commands",
            "app/controllers",
            "app/models",
            "app/validators",
            "app/database/migrations",
            "app/database/seeds",
            "app/tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

I've added `"intervention/helper": "dev-master"` under the `require` directive and when I do `composer update` on my local copy of the website, everything works fine and I can use the library.

I did a `git push` and `pull` to get it onto my live server, and when doing a `composer update` it doesn't download this library. This is the entire output of the command: http://pastebin.com/UgPNTaDw

I also tried `composer install` and `composer update` for a second time but neither worked. I've also verified that git retrieved the new `composer.json` file on the live server, and it has.

Why isn't composer recognizing the changes and downloading the library?

Comment: Looks like the log says the opposite at line 24:
 - Installing intervention/helper (dev-master ad8b992)

Are you sure that composer didn't download it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides the fact that your log does exactly tell you the "missing" library was downloaded, I have some general comment:

Are you sure you want to use EVERY library in DEVELOPMENT quality? Because that is what you enabled with the "minimum stability" flag: You are allowing EVERYTHING in possibly broken state from whatever development branch the libraries provide.

And the second thing is: You are supposed to update only once, on your development machine! Then test that everything still is working, and commit the `composer.lock` file!

Then push and pull that change to wherever you need it, and there only `composer install` - because you probably want the exact SAME library versions that you tested with, not anything slightly newer with possibly broken commits.

If you only want to use that particular library as development version, you should add that flag to the version requirement:

```
"intervention/helper": "dev-master@dev"
```

On the other hand, this library has released versions, so it might be better to require them...

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. To be honest I'm not very familiar with composer and wasn't sure the best way to use it. What you said seems like a sensible way.